# How to change page orientation to landscape?

Tags: python, ms-word, orientation, landscape, python-docx

I want to change the orientation to landscape for only certain pages in the word that I'm creating using python-docx.
Is this possible?
If yes, how?
If no, is there any other option to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page orientation is specified on a section-by-section basis. So if you want to change back and forth, you'll need to add a section break at each point you want to change from portrait to landscape or vice versa.

This page in the documentation should give you what you need.

http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/sections.html